# Unable to install Linux Mint 17 on hardware that uses AMD APU (A5800k) with MSI motherboard

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I and many other users of Linux Mint are not able to install Mint 17 on hardware that uses AMD APU (A5800k) with MSI mobo. I understand that the issue has been noted but I cannot find a fix to this problem. Linux Mint 16, however, installed without issue on the same hardware.

The Mint 17 installation almost installed, but the pc rebooted after just a few seconds as it began to display the first screen shot of the installation process. So near yet so far!

Any suggestions when a remedy may be forthcoming?

Comment: Has a report been made to the Linux Mint team? Wouldn't they be the appropriate folks to ask?

Comment: You would probably get a better result by asking on the Linux Mint forums.  Is it this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1309578

Comment: This what i did, while Installation and after the installation i have edited the grub and updated the grub and its working fine https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z

Comment: I had this problem trying to upgrade from Mint 15 to 16. I have found a completely different approach has given a solution. Mint Deban works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Mint16 I received the "unable to install grub" error and used the following process to resolve:

In "preparing" (drives) screen selected manual, continue
selected my fat32 (boot?) partition, changed type to "boot EFI" in drop down menu
selected my ext4 (system) partition, changed type to ext4 mount to / "ok/continue
selected my "boot EFI" partition to install bootloader

and this worked!

Note: selections may not be exact as this is from memory ;()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my AMD 5400K APU. It would crash during installation or any time the load got too heavy.

My solution was to update the firmware on the Mobo.

EDIT:

I honestly have no idea why this fixed the problem, but apparently the newer kernel didn't like the older (probably buggy) firmware.